# Please help me to know what is happening in this code

Tags: c++

```cpp
string kthDistinct(vector<string>& arr, int k) {
    unordered_map<string, int> m;
    for (auto &s : arr)
        ++m[s];
//Frome here
    for (auto &s : arr)
        if (m[s] == 1 && --k == 0)
            return s;
    return "";
//to here 
}
```

Especially in this part
for (auto &s : arr)
if (m[s] == 1 && --k == 0)
return s;

Comment: If you aren't familiar with that syntax, I'd suggest a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That block of code is a bit on the dense side. If we rewrite the same logic in a more verbose manner, we get:

```
for (auto &s : arr) {
  if (m[s] == 1) {
    k -= 1;
    if (k == 0) {
      return s;
    } 
  }
}
return string{""};
```

Since `m` contains the number of time a string appears within `arr`, we can interpret this as:

"Return the `k`th string of `arr` that appears only once within `arr`, otherwise, return the empty string."